# Setting value of item in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that will grab the value from a text box once a button is clicked, run it through an external database and then return a result to me. That result will then be placed into another text box.

My issue is that the coding I have takes a little bit too long (At least I think this is the issue) to get a result from the external database, and sets the value of the text box when it is not ready.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Declaring the variable.
    var mname = "";

    $('#btnMN').click(function() {
        //Pull data from name
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find(':input[type="text"][name="name[]"]').val();
        //Run through database
        $.post('test1.php', { name: name}, function(data){
            mname = data;
        });
        //Set text box with return data
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.master').val(mname);
        mname = "";

    });

    </script>
```

I cannot put the "Set text box with return data" part in another function, because I will then lose the "this" selector telling it exactly which text box to set, because I have a dynamic form that I can add/remove rows to.

```
    <tr id="input_11" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        <td valign="top" align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;"><span style="color:#00CD00;"><BR>Victim:</span></td>
        <td valign="top">Name:<input type="text" name="name[]" size="35"/><input type="button" id="btnMN" value="Mastername Check" /></td>
        <td class="master">Mastername:<textarea readonly class="master" name="master[]" rows="8" cols="28"></textarea></td>
        <td>Statement:<textarea name="statement[]" rows="8" cols="28"  placeholder="Paste statement here."></textarea></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _value of the text box when it is not ready._ ?

Comment: Put the set the textbox return data part into the post request

Comment: the a in ajax stands for asynchronous

Comment: The jQuery code called out to a php function, which took a moment to process. While this was processing, it continued with the rest of the code. Meaning.. it set the text box to the variable that was supposed to be set by the external php code, and then the variable was being set after the text box value was set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.post()` is an asynchronous (that's the "a" in "ajax") call.  So it sends a request but continues processing the rest of the function while it waits for a response.  Anything based on that response must go in the callaback.

```
    $('#btnMN').click(function() {
        //Pull data from name
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find(':input[type="text"][name="name[]"]').val();
        //Store element we want to update
        var master =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.master');
        //Run through database
        $.post('test1.php', { name: name}, function(data){
            master.val(data);
        });


    });
```

Comment: I had no idea I could do that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Set the value **in** your callback function.

```
 $.post('test1.php', { name: name}, function(data){
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.master').val(data);
  });
```

Comment: While right about the callaback, the problem with this solution is that `this` inside the callback is not the originally clicked element any more - I think it is the request object or something.  So `$(this).closest` will not behave as you want.  Need to save either the clicked object or the target to a variable first (see my answer)